# Turn an AWS Split list into multiple blocks of yaml/json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have an exported parameter in AWS Cloudformation which describes a list of Cidrs.

We need to create a EC2 security group entry for every item in the list, i.e.

```
SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: <1st-entry-in-list>
          IpProtocol: -1
        - CidrIp: <2nd-entry-in-list>
          IpProtocol: -1
        - CidrIp: <3rd-entry-in-list>
          IpProtocol: -1
        - etc....
```

Is there a way we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way we can do this?

**No** in plain CFN, as this would require looping mechanism which CFN does not have. You would have to develop a CFN [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for that.